# .Net API getting Timeouts connecting to SQL Server when high requests

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, api

I have an API written in C#. Each call needs a connection to the database to do something. Everything works great unless there is a spike in calls (1,000+ in a minute), then the API gets timeouts when trying to establish a connection with the database.

I thought I had it all set up correctly for opening/closing/etc but I am relatively new to C#, so maybe I am doing something incorrectly.

Here are some snippets, please advise on areas that could make this able to handle higher throughput, specific problem is repeated connections.

My setup is

- Controller (with service dependency injection),
- Service (with repository dependency injection), and
- Repository (with DBContext dependency injection) + Entity Framework Core.

DB/MSFT related NuGets

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v6.0.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v6.0.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools v6.0.1
- Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms v6.0.1

Things I have tried:

- Fiddling with connection string to allow more and more connections
- Creating a new `CBContext` for each request using `DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDBContext>()`
- Cursing

Snippet from `StartUp.cs`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     ... 
        // define the context pool
        services.AddDbContextPool<MyDBContext>(
                o => o.UseSqlServer(SecretFetcher.GetConnectionString())); 

        // Connection string looks like: 
        // Server=<server_url>,<port>;Database=<database_name>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
     ...

        // how I add the repos for dependency injection
        services.AddTransient<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();

    }
```

Snippet from a repository that talks to the database:

```
    public async Task Create(MyEntity entity)
    {
        // we do not need to return anything on this Create action
        await MyDBContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);

        // save new record
        await MyDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Snippet from error when a flood of requests come in:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: `Execution Timeout Expired` it seems you need to optimize your database queries. you can debug the executed queries, see what you can do to tweak them, if there is a long-running queries, fix them. you can have a temporary fix by setting the `CommandTimeout` to 0, (the default is 30 seconds I believe). just to buy you time fixing the main issue.

Comment: The big issue with Entity Framework, and most ORMs, is that they encourage N+1 style queries. In other words, they basically make you query a main table, then query a child table row-by-row, which is really slow. They also can't usually do bulk inserts and updates. For performance, write your own SQL, and use a micro-ORM like Dapper just to do the mapping.

Comment: There is not a query to optimize.  We are using the entity framework and this particular method that is causing an issue is a simple record insert on a single table.

Comment: In case that there might be some issues with context pool, you can try `AddDbContext` instead of `AddDbContextPool`

Comment: @tia good idea.  this is what I had originally but switched to DBContextPool because of the same error.  : /